# How to set up a proper prior sensitivity analysis?

Tags: bayesian, prior, sensitivity-analysis

Working with Bayesian econometrics I am regularly faced to the (valid) question:

> How does your prior choice affect the results?

Given my parameter space is of rather low-dimension I may come up with some pictures, however, is there a common procedure/methodology exist which is common sense in order to convince the audience that varying hyperparameters does not alter the results in a crucial form? I personally think, authors dealing with Bayesian Econometrics should carefully evaluate the effect of prior choices (and in the best case provide a thorough analysis in their papers appendices), so, I would be very happy to see some good examples in literature.